# How does this Baritone singer sing so high?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, tenor

[Caleb Hyles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qUxMErlSl8) has the low end richness or a Baritone, but the range of a Tenor. What singing voice type is this, and if I'm correct that he's a Baritone, how does he sing so damn high with ease?

Comment: Some people are just lucky with a big range. Karen Carpenter had a range of four octaves, so could be put into several categories. Luck of the draw!

Comment: look at  his eyes, his mouth, his tongue, his gesteres, his chest, his breast, his hear!  
then you know how! :)

Comment: I myself have a vocal range of more than 3 octaves (just how much more depends on what vocal exercises I do). Notes I can sing include low C and the C above high C.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you'd call this style 'Contemporary Music Theatre'.  Free from opera's requirement to match orchestral volume unamplified, singers often manage to integrate chest, head and falsetto into one 'voice'.  Good, isn't he!

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is years old but I'd like to toss in my notion that Caleb is indeed a tenor. He has a very tenor-y sound to his mid and high range, with only the very bottom of his range sounding baritone. He's very well-practiced, but most baritones can hold notes in the mid-2nd octave much better than he can. His E2s in [Let Them Come](https://youtu.be/iqjVy94lnHE?t=89) and [Home](https://youtu.be/DpcgOh7Q1Hk?t=57), while low notes for a tenor to be hitting, are very shaky and it almost sounds like he's about to fall off the note at any point. Compare this to a baritone like [Frank Sinatra's E2](https://youtu.be/HZse_nH1hSo?t=167) or [Bing Crosby's E2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7pe4Z5DHYM&t=134s). Their larynxes are in much more natural positions and are more stable in pitch than any tenor E2 could be. Caleb can belt with a chest-y sound up to D5 and mix further to Bb5, which is insanely high for any male singer. Most trained baritones struggle to maintain a chesty sound starting at around A4. His versatility in range is thanks to the flexibility of his vocal cords, but also the style in which he sings. Modern pop baritones like John Legend and Chris Martin promote a sound that emulates tenors, because a lighter vocal styling is what's popular in music. Caleb Hyles seems to be doing the opposite in some of his music, emulating a richer sound by darkening both his highs and lows to increase the dramatics of his singing, and a byproduct of that is sounding, at least to those less educated about voice type, baritone-ish. Additionally, and less importantly, his M1 register seems to bottom out around E2, whereas most baritones' cutoff is D2-C2 (if u want examples John Legend's lowest M1 is [D2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XlpNMWoPZ3U&t=34s), Eddie Vedder's was [C#2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3YuMvviDQ4&t=154s), and Bing Crosby's was [C2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B28P4x4Acz4&t=122s)).